# Array list não armazena os dados

Tags: java, arraylist

```
//------------------------------------------ Classe diario (metodo localizar aluno)--------------------------------

package gerenciamento;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Diario {
    String nomeDisciplina;
    int cargaHoraria;

//----------------------------------------------Adicionar aluno-------------------------------------------

    ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();

    public int adicionarAluno(int matricula, String nome, float nota1, float nota2, float nota3, int faltas) {
        localizarAluno(matricula);
        if (localizarAluno(matricula) == null) {
            Aluno instancia = new Aluno(matricula, nome, nota1, nota2, nota3, faltas);
            alunos.add(instancia);
            return 1;
        } else return 0;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------Remover aluno-------------------------------------------    
    public int removerAluno(int m) {
        localizarAluno(m);
        if (localizarAluno(m) == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++) {
                if (alunos.get(i).getMatricula() == m) {
                    alunos.remove(i);
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }

//----------------------------------------------Localizar aluno-------------------------------------------    

    public Aluno localizarAluno(int matricula) {
        Aluno aluno = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++) {
            Aluno a = alunos.get(i);
            if (a.getMatricula() == matricula) {
                aluno = alunos.get(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return aluno;
    }

//----------------------------------------------Construtor-------------------------------------------

    Diario(String nomeDisciplina, int cargaHoraria) {
        setNomeDisciplina(nomeDisciplina);
        if (cargaHoraria != 40 || cargaHoraria != 60 || cargaHoraria != 80 || cargaHoraria != 120) {
            setCargaHoraria(40);
        } else {
            setCargaHoraria(cargaHoraria);
        }
    }

    //----------------------------Getters e Setters------------------------------
    public String getNomeDisciplina() {
        return nomeDisciplina;
    }

    public void setNomeDisciplina(String nomeDisciplina) {
        this.nomeDisciplina = nomeDisciplina;
    }

    public int getCargaHoraria() {
        return cargaHoraria;
    }

    public void setCargaHoraria(int cargaHoraria) {
        this.cargaHoraria = cargaHoraria;
    }
}


//-------------------------Main-----------------

package gerenciamento;

        import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gerenciamento {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int op;
        Diario diario = null;

        Scanner Teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------Menu-----------------------------------------------
        do {
            System.out.println("Escolha uma opção: ");
            System.out.println("1-Criar Diaro");
            System.out.println("2-Adicionar aluno ao diario");
            System.out.println("3-Remover aluno do diaro");
            System.out.println("4-Consultar aluno");
            System.out.println("5-Imprimir diario");
            System.out.println("6-Sair do programa");
            op = Teclado.nextInt();

            switch (op) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Informe o nome da disciplina: ");
                    Teclado.nextLine();
                    String n = Teclado.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Informe a carga horaria da disciplina(40, 60, 80 ou 120): ");
                    int c = Teclado.nextInt();
                    diario = new Diario(n, c);
                    System.out.println("Criação realizada com sucesso!");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (diario == null) {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum diario localizado! Tente novamente.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Informe o numero da matricula: ");
                        int matricula = Teclado.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Informe o nome do aluno: ");
                        Teclado.nextLine();
                        String nome = Teclado.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Informe nota 1 do aluno: ");
                        float nota1 = Teclado.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Informe nota 2 do aluno: ");
                        float nota2 = Teclado.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Informe nota 3 do aluno: ");
                        float nota3 = Teclado.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Informe o numero de faltas: ");
                        int faltas = Teclado.nextInt();
                        diario.adicionarAluno(matricula, nome, nota1, nota2, nota3, faltas);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (diario == null) {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum diario localizado! Tente novamente.");
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("Digite o numero da matricula do aluno a ser removido: ");
                        int m = Teclado.nextInt();
                        diario.localizarAluno(m);
                        diario.removerAluno(m);
                        if (diario.removerAluno(m) == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Este aluno não existe no diario.");
                        } else System.out.println("Aluno removido com sucesso");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:

                    if (diario == null) {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum diario localizado! Tente novamente.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Informe a matricula a ser buscada: ");
                        int m = Teclado.nextInt();
                        diario.localizarAluno(m);
                        System.out.println("Aluno " + diario.localizarAluno(m));
                    }

                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (diario == null) {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum diario localizado! Tente novamente.");
                    } else {


                        System.out.println("Disciplina: " + diario.getNomeDisciplina());
                        System.out.println("Cargahoraria: " + diario.getCargaHoraria());
                        System.out.println("Alunos: ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < diario.alunos.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println(diario.alunos.get(i).getNome());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (op != 6);

    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código referente ao método `localizarAluno()`. Mas lembre-se que quanto mais código você colocar (pelo menos todos que se relacionarem ao problema), melhor a chance de encontrar a falha. Muitas vezes teimamos que o erro está em um lugar, mas descobrimos que está em outro.

Comment: Seria bom você editar a pergunta e colocar a classe Diario inteira e também a classe onde o método `localizarAluno()` se encontra para vermos como o mesmo funciona. Só aí poderemos ter uma ideia do problema e dessa forma ajudáo-lo.

Comment: Pronto galera ta ai, tentei corrigir os erros aqui, até rodou, mas o case 2 sempre da erro, o case de adicionar objeto ao array

Answer (score 0):

```
Diario diario = null;
```

para

```
ArrayList<Diario> arrayListDiario = new List<Diario>();

if(arraytListDiario.size() == '0')
else
insertUser();
```